# sympy plot conflict with piecewise function

Tags: python, plot, sympy, piecewise

I have created a piecewise function using sympy:

```
x= symbols('x')

XL = (1-x)**2
XH = (x-1)**1.5

XX= Piecewise((XL,x<=1),(XH,x>1))
plot(XX,(x,0,2),adaptive=False, num_of_points=200)
```

It works to calculate `XX` at any value of `x` between 0 and 2 (only range of interest).

When I plot it, it returns an error that a negative number can't be raised to a fractional power, which should never happen, as it's only when `x` is greater than 1 that the fractional power applies.

Is it processing both pieces over the full range for some reason? any thoughts?

Comment: My guess is that the issue is numerical noise around zero. Please report this as a bug on github https://github.com/sympy/sympy/. A workaround would be taking the real part of your expression and plotting it.

Comment: In other words, plot `re(XX)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the workaround i used was abs(x-1):

```
x= symbols('x')
XL = (1-x)**2
XH = abs(x-1)**1.5

XX= Piecewise((XL,x<=1),(XH,x>1))
plot(XX,(x,0,2),adaptive=False, num_of_points=200)
```

it's correct for when the number will actually be used, and avoids the error. I submitted the bug as well on Github.